# NameVirtualHost *:80 and 443 has no VirtualHosts on centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

Since I added IPs to my server, I have a lot of issues when starting `apache`.

I always have these errors below:

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Sometimes it prevents `apache` to start, and sometimes not

My conf:

> OS : CentOS 6.6
>
> Apache : 2.2.15

My `httpd.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ....
</VirtualHost>
#more than 500 others <VirtualHost *:80> for each domain
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have duplicate `NameVirtualHost *:[port]` entries?

Comment: Do you have the listen line like: `Listen :80` and/or `Listen :443`?

Comment: @fgbreel yes both

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen no just these 2 lines

Comment: How did you add IPs to your server? Did you change anything in the apache config at the same time? If so, what?

Comment: Check your listening line. Are you listening on *:80 and *:443 or specific IP addresses. If the latter, make sure that all the desired IP addresses are properly listed. Also, this is just a warning, is your site actually working?

Answer (score 2):

Your config can work for some times, but mostly it unworkable. Working config look like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ....
</VirtualHost>


NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName www.domain.com
      ....     
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

Or made separate file for vhosts.conf (In centos your path for file will be /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf). If you need separate tls certificate for every virtual host you need some additional changes.